# jquery mobile horizontal controlgroup, mixed that includes text box

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Im trying to create a horizontal control group that consists of 2 options boxes and one text input field. However, the documentation on the JQM website doesnt cover this and I cant find a way to make the fields align correctly.
It currently does this:

[image]

Is there a way to align it properly? I currently have the options box and the text box in separate grids but it leaves a big gap between them which I don't want.
Code:

```
 <div class="ui-grid-c">
  <div class='ui-block-a' >
    <div class='ui-body ui-body-a gridContent' style="border:none;">
      <div class="ui-field-contain ">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <select name="sortBy" id="sortBy"  data-mini="true" >
            <option id="all" name="all" value="all">Show All</option>
            <option id="size" name="size" value="size">Physical Size</option>
            <option id="sizecode" name="sizecode" value="sizecode">Sizecode</option>
          </select>
          <select name="how" id="how"  data-mini="true" >
            <option id="lessThan" name="lessThan" value="lessThan">&#60;&#61;</option>
            <option id="equal" name="equal" value="equal">&#61;</option>
            <option id="greaterThan" name="greaterThan" value="greaterThan">&#62;&#61;</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" name="searchBox" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search" value="" data-mini="true">
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='ui-block-b'>
    <div class='ui-body ui-body-a  gridContent' style='border:none;'>
      <input type="text" name="searchBox" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search" value="" data-mini="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='ui-block-c'>
    <div class='ui-body ui-body-a' style='border:0px;'>
      <input type="text" name="textinput-5" id="textinput-5" placeholder="Text input" value="" data-mini="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='ui-block-d'>
    <div class='ui-body ui-body-a' style='border:0px;'>
      <input type="text" name="textinput-5" id="textinput-5" placeholder="Text input" value="" data-mini="true">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- close grid -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the **[TextInputs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/controlgroup/#Textinputs)** example at the jQM site?

> Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8G6cP/)**

```
  <div class="ui-field-contain ">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="false">
      <select name="sortBy" id="sortBy"  >
        <option id="all" name="all" value="all">Show All</option>
        <option id="size" name="size" value="size">Physical Size</option>
        <option id="sizecode" name="sizecode" value="sizecode">Sizecode</option>
      </select>
      <select name="how" id="how"   >
        <option id="lessThan" name="lessThan" value="lessThan">&#60;&#61;</option>
        <option id="equal" name="equal" value="equal">&#61;</option>
        <option id="greaterThan" name="greaterThan" value="greaterThan">&#62;&#61;</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="searchBox" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search" value=""  data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn" >
    </fieldset>


.controlgroup-textinput{
    padding-top:.22em;
    padding-bottom:.22em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great! However, I want this to be data-mini="true" but the text box is slightly taller than the other fields, leaving a small lip. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @Janey, you can play with the height to make it work mini: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8G6cP/1/